# Echo Adsense Javascript Block via PhP

Tags: javascript, php, adsense

I'm trying to echo out a block of javascript to show an adsense ad.  I've looked it up and this appears to be the answer; however, its throwing me the error of:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

```
    $ad = '
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Responsive ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-8659497818387773"
     data-ad-slot="1059972100"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>';

echo $ad;
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: _that_ piece of code is valid. Your error is coming from somewhere else

Comment: In the spirit of "Is it plugged in?" -- is that enclosed within the php tag `<?php $ad = ' ... stuff ... '; echo $ad; ?>`

Comment: Is this *everything* in your file?